# How do I insert multiple joined models in Laravel 5

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying insert a sample user into my database.

My database contains 3 models, these should all be populated at the same time. The models are: Users, Profiles and Teams.

- Each User has one Profile (one to one relationship).
- Each User can
  be part of many Teams and each Team can have many Users (many to many
  relationship).

My models are setup correctly with the relevant `belongsTo()` / `hasMany()` references etc.

In laravel, my code looks like this:

```
$user =     new User([ 'email' => 'sample@sample.com', 'password' => bcrypt('password1'), 'username'=> 'sampleuser']);
$profile =  new Profile(['name' => 'Sample','bio'  => 'All about me']);
$team =     new Team(['name' => 'SuperAdmins']);

$user->profile()->save($profile);
$user->teams()->attach($team, ['type' => 4]);
```

How can I get this to work>? this does not work, with my console citing `'user_id' cannot be null` when inserting into the profile table.

**EDIT:**
Thanks, to the answer from Ross Wilson, I went with:

```
    $user =     new User([ 'email' => 'sample@sample.com', 'password' => bcrypt('password1'), 'username'=> 'sampleuser']);
    $user->save();

    $profile =  new Profile(['name' => 'Sample','bio'  => 'All about me']);
    $user->profile()->save($profile);

    $team =     new Team(['name' => 'SuperAdmins']);
    $user->teams()->save($team, ['type' => 4]);
```

Comment: you want to create a team for each User insert or just pickup a team and attach user to this teamId ?

Comment: @zorx In this case, it is actually create a new team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example you never actually persist the `User` model.

Add `$user->save();` before saving profile relationship.

You'll also need to persist the `$team` before attaching it to the `User`

Hope this helps!